# What is a good identification key for European mushrooms?

Tags: mycology, literature, mushroom

I live in the Netherlands, and I am looking for an identification key for mushrooms. 
Are there any keys you could share?

Comment: [1](http://www.mushroomexpert.com/major_groups.html)

[2](http://www.rogersmushrooms.com/gallery/chooser.asp)

[3](http://www.mycokey.com/newMycoKeySite/MycoKeyIdentQuick.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various types of Mushroom identification Sites. you can take help from:

1. [Mushroomexpert](http://www.mushroomexpert.com/major_groups.html)
2. [Rogersmushrooms](http://www.rogersmushrooms.com/gallery/chooser.asp)
3. [MycoKey 4.0](http://www.mycokey.com/newMycoKeySite/MycoKeyIdentQuick.html)

[image]

Source: MycoKey 4.0